# How to resize dxDataGrid when column resizing

Tags: html, angularjs, devextreme

I can resize dxDataGrid column, but that column overwriting beside column.

Is there any option to expand (resize) dxDataGrid when column resizing

```
  $scope.dataGridOptions = {
                   bindingOptions: { dataSource: 'gridDataSource' },


                   allowColumnResizing: true,
                   columnAutoWidth: true,
                   hoverStateEnabled: true,
                   allowColumnReordering: true,
                   filterRow: {
                       visible: true
                   },
                   paging: {
                       enabled: false
                   },
                    ..............
                   ..............
```

I am using html 5 and angular:

```
<div id="gridContainer" dx-data-grid="dataGridOptions" ></div>
```

Comment: Currently, dxDataGrid doesn't support such functionally out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

The DevExtreme team added this option out-of-the-box in v17.1. You can learn more about this from the following DevExpress blog post:

[DevExtreme DataGrid - Advanced Column Resizing](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2017/05/04/html5-javascript-datagrid-enhancements-v17-1.aspx)